# Call graph for preprocessed C code (*.i file)

Tags: doxygen

I have a preprocessed C code with gcc, as output i have *.i files.
can  i use preprocessed code (*.i files) to generate call graph with doxygen?
if it is possible thanks for telling me how.

Comment: Read about EXTENSION_MAPPING, INPUT, FILE_PATTERNS and preprocessing in either the Doxyfile or the documentation. Problem here will probably be that you have 2 input file (.c and .i) with similar contents where you might want to leave out the .c file (when at least the .i file still contains the doxygen comment)

Comment: Thanks Albert, i just set i=C in EXTENSION_MAPPING and FILE_PATTERNS to *.c,*.i and doxygen treats *.i files as C files. But i still have some problems with *.i file, i have about 3000 *.i files for witch i want to generate call graph , when i run doxygen for all the files , doxygen carshes, i try doxygen for only 50 files and it works as well.My question is there a limitation about the number of files that doxygen can treat or maybe the cause of crash is the contents of *.i files?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there are no limits (unless set by the OS). What OS are you using, which doxygen version. can you generate a stack trace?

Comment: Hi Albert,
1)doxygen version i use:1.8.9.1
2)I run it on windows XP (Core 2Duo CPU,2.93Ghz,3.25Go RAM)

3)when doxygen craches , log message was:

Searching for tag less structs...
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
*** Doxygen has finished

4) 
in the config i set LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0,the last Time i run it before it craches, lookup cache was:
42814/65536 hits=22255551 misses=46238

5)Have you an idea how to generate a stack trace when running doxygen on windows?

Comment: I don't really know how to get a stack trace on windows. Did you try to observe the memory usage (in the task manager or equal) to see if you run out of memory / hit the limits of Xp regarding memory usage.